# Implementing Akka in Play Framework 2.4 for Scala

Tags: scala, akka, playframework-2.4

I am trying to replicate the basic example proposed in the [Integrating with Akka, Play 2.4 for Scala doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4). But I have difficulties in placing the final pieces together...

I have defined the actor (see paragraph [Writing actors](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAkka#Writing-actors)) at `app/actors/HelloActor.scala` with the following code:

```
package actors

import akka.actor._

object HelloActor {
    def props = Props[HelloActor]

    case class SayHello(name: String)
}

class HelloActor extends Actor {
    import HelloActor._

    def receive = {
        case SayHello(name: String) =>
            sender() ! "Hello, " + name
    }
}
```

Then (see [Creating and using actors](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAkka#Creating-and-using-actors)) I suppose I should create a controller at `app/controllers/Hello.scala` with something like:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import akka.actor._
import javax.inject._

import actors.HelloActor

@Singleton
class Hello @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

    val helloActor = system.actorOf(HelloActor.props, "hello-actor")

    ...

}
```

The question: where and how I utilize the code in the following paragraph [Asking things of actors](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAkka#Asking-things-of-actors) to have a working solution? I have tried to add it to the above `Hello.scala` controller but without success.

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask
implicit val timeout = 5.seconds

def sayHello(name: String) = Action.async {
    (helloActor ? SayHello(name)).mapTo[String].map { message =>
        Ok(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work as expected, what errors do you have ?

Comment: with `implicit val timeout = 5.seconds` I wag getting the following error `value seconds is not a member of Int Note: implicit value timeout is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type` plus I was not 100% sure about how to place everything in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I had some problems with defining the implicit timeout, this is the working controller:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import akka.actor._
import javax.inject._

import actors.HelloActor
import actors.HelloActor.SayHello

import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

@Singleton
class Hello @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

  val helloActor = system.actorOf(HelloActor.props, "hello-actor")

  implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5.seconds

  def sayHello(name: String) = Action.async { 

    (helloActor ? SayHello(name)).mapTo[String].map { message ⇒
      Ok(message)
    }
  }
}
```

Plus I added the following route in `app/conf/routes`:

```
# Actor test
GET     /hello/:name                controllers.Hello.sayHello(name)
```

Comment: Probably if you write something like `implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5.seconds` (note I've added explicitly the type) will work, this is because with the explicit type an implicit conversion will happen.

Comment: @EndeNeu yes, thank you, it works, I am editing my answer to reflect this